# How to present a view controller from tab bar button

Tags: ios, swift

I have a tab bar controller with 3 tab bar buttons.  At the moment it looks like this:

```
class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let firstTabBarController = FirstController()
    let firstTabBarNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: firstTabBarController)
    firstTabBarNavigationController.tabBarItem.title = "First Tab"

    let secondTabBarController = SecondController()
    let secondTabBarNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: secondTabBarController)
    secondTabBarController.tabBarItem.title = "Second Tab"

    let thirdTabBarController = ThirdController()
    let thirdTabBarNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: thirdTabBarController)
    thirdTabBarNavigationController.tabBarItem.title = "Third Tab"

    viewControllers = [firstTabBarNavigationController, secondTabBarNavigationController, thirdTabBarNavigationController]

}
}
```

Right now, with the code above, all the view controllers are sitting inside the `CustomTabBarController`

I want the the middle tab bar button, the `secondTabBarNavigationController` to present a view controller, specifically the `UIImagePickerController` for a user to select an image, similar to Instagram.

How can this be achieved? I am not using storyboards

Comment: Why are you setting the `tabBarController.delegate` property instead of `self.delegate` ? What you are doing is wrong because you're trying to set the delegate of an optional `super tabBarController`. Edit this and it works

Comment: Ahhh I see, I had no idea! Thank you Luca, works perfectly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just implement the `func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool` delegate method of the tabBar controller.

When the desired tab is pressed, present a controller and return `false`, otherwise return `true`.

I would also associate an empty `UIViewController` instance to the tab.

Ex.

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    if (tab for this controller is equal to the expected tab) {
        // present you controller
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: How does one check which tab has been pressed?

Comment: That's on you @luke . You should be able to check what's the corresponding tab of a specific `UIViewController` instance. At least is what the `UITabBarController` pattern expects.

Comment: I'm a little confused here.  I have no idea what `if tabFor(viewController) == .cameraTab` means.

Comment: @luke Sorry, it's just a placeholder to make you understand what you should implement there, I'm gonna replace with a comment

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something - `func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool` never seems to get called when I click a tab. When I type `shouldSelect`, autocomplete doesn't allow me to select the function neither.

Comment: You have to set the tabBar controller as `UITabBarControllerDelegate` by setting the `delegate` property to `self`

Comment: Still the same issue (although it autocompletes now), the function isn't being called. I've edited my question